# "Spread" Weight Paint/Simulation Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, weight-painting, simulation-nodes

I was wondering how to to spread "weight/selection paint" (like you can a DPaint image sequence) using Geometry/Simulation Nodes, based on Object Proximity. It seems like there a simple solution, and yet I am unable to figure it out.
An easy way to describe what I am looking for is an expanding object trail.
Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

you can use this node setup here:

[image]

[image]

I am sure there are better way doing this, but it's a possible way.
It is also not really performant because it generates more geometry per frame.

What it essentially does is adding all this spheres and scales them, uses these combined spheres as proximity object and paints by this the grid.

https://youtu.be/Z_tN_q4DTVY